# Is there a way to go back to a screen that's not in the same stackNavigator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have two screens: `UserProfile` and `EventEdit`. Both are in different stackNavigators

```
const ProfileDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Profile: UserProfile,
    ProfileEdit: UserProfileEdit,
    ProfilePreferences: UserProfilePreferences,
    ProfilePrivacy: UserProfilePrivacy,
    ProfileSupport: UserProfileSupport
  }
);

const EventStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Events: Events,
    EventEdit: EventEdit,
    NewEvent: NewEvent
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Events',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false
    }
  }
);
```

What I am trying to do is go on the `EventEdit` screen from `UserProfile`, and then go back to `UserProfile`. The problem is that I've tried with `navigation.goBack();` but that sends me to the `Events` screen, rather than to `UserProfile`.
Also, I've tried by putting `EventEdit` into the `ProfileDrawer` stack, but since a user can have multiple events when I do this method, it only sends me to the first event I select, but I wouldn't go to any other event I could have.

Also, I forgot to mention that the user can access `EventEdit` from multiple screens, sometimes those screens are in other stack navigators, such as the case here.

My `react-nativagion` version is `"^4.2.2"`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please always mention your `React-Navigation` version while asking question.

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar Edited to add the react-navigation version.

Comment: thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `TopLevelNavigator` and access these routes from any stack to any other stack.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/navigating-without-navigation-prop